# TableLayoutPanel adding rows and columns at runtime

Tags: .net, vb.net, tablelayoutpanel

In a user control, at runtime, I'm creating 5 rows and 3 columns in a tablelayoutpanel. The cells I fill with controls: label, textbox, checkbox..... works...

This is my code:

```
Private Sub GenerateGUI(Cboxes As Integer, Tboxes As Integer)

    tlp.Controls.Clear()
    tlp.RowStyles.Clear()
    tlp.ColumnStyles.Clear()

    If Cboxes > 0 And Tboxes > 0 Then 
        tlp.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 20%))
        tlp.RowCount = Checkboxes

        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))
        tlp.ColumnCount = 3

        For i = 1 To Checkboxes
            Dim L As New Label, TB As New TextBox, CB As New CheckBox

            With L
                .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
                .Visible = True
                .Text = Chr(64 + i) '65 = capital A
                .Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11, FontStyle.Bold)
                .BackColor = Color.Aqua
            End With

            With TB
                .Name = "txt" & i
                .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
                .Visible = True
                .Multiline = True
                .Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11, FontStyle.Regular)
                .ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical
            End With

            With CB
                .Name = "chk" & i
                .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
                .Visible = True
                .BackColor = Color.LightGray
           End With


            tlp.Controls.Add(L, 0, i - 1)
            tlp.Controls.Add(TB, 1, i - 1)
            tlp.Controls.Add(CB, 2, i - 1)
        Next
End Sub
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

In the picture you also see how it should be. What am I doing wrong? I'm out of ideas.....

Comment: I have observed that you haven't awarded a single answer yet. You just ask, get the solution to your problem, open a new question and ask again. Honestly, I don't think that this is the  right way to learn/grow as a developer, but it is completely up to you. What I can say is that you will not get any help from me firstly because I don't see the point of your attitude and secondly because you are a pretty ungrateful person.

Comment: im sorry.. im so much into developing right now that i just didnt think about it. and i planned to create a new acc bc my username is kinda 'strange'..
anyway if u feel like answering or not... ill go to the 2 other questions now and award them.... was not a bad intension. honestly.

#edit:
24 hours... so its too late now :(
im sorry again...
how can i award e.g. ur answer above?

Comment: award the questions if you consider that your question has been answered properly. This helps others to know about it and rewards the effort of the answerer by increasing his/her ranking a bit. This last point is secondary but well... is the best way to show your appreciation.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment, you cannot award it. In this post you don't have any answers, if you go to one of your other questions, you would see a tick sign on the left hand size of the given answer, if you click on it, you would award it as the right answer.

Comment: And regarding your question, your code is pretty complete already, why not doing a further effort to tackle it down instead of asking? For example, in your picture you are are complaining about the width of a column, but there is no reference in your code to columns?! if  tlp.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 20%)) affect rows, why not trying the equivalent for columns tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 50))? Also you talk about 75% but don't see this value in your code. Do some trial and error + research and will surely fix this problem easily.

Comment: yes.. i realized that its only possible for questions too now :P
if u had written as answer u would have an award now :P

im doing try and error since 48 hrs... its just that i posted the code as clean as possible..

.autosize.. shouldnt this indicate.. that the columns will have the size regarding their content? im setting the content's sizes.. imho it shoulda work that way...

the funny thing is, whatever i set for columnstyle.absolut.. it has NO EFFECT..

Comment: tlp.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 20%)) #

tlp.RowCount = Checkboxes #

tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 50)) #

tlp.ColumnCount = 3 #

it stays like in the picture...

Comment: Thanks for the offer but I am not interested in getting an award for an answer I haven't replied. The aforementione points are just show an appreciation, but don't have any real value (not too me) and thus I will not do anything to get points other than the right thing (= answering questions).

Comment: Regarding your problems with the code, what you think about that: you don't know how works the TableLayoutPanel, the columns/rows; so why not relying on the simplest code possible to understand the behaviour, instead keep including controls affecting this behaviour further? Why you don't start a project from scratch, put a TableLayoutPanel on it with 3 columns (colour the background and set CellBorderStyle to single to see everything properly) and then start to play around with the Column/Row properties and see how your changes affect the TableLayoutPanel behaviour. (out of space)

Comment: Once you have understood the behaviour properly, you should include other controls, just one (which has its own width/height) and see how this affects your column/row variations. If you do this step by step and being fresh (not at 12 in the night), you might get a perfect grasp of what is going on in less than half an hour; much quicker than posting a question/waiting for the answer/arguing with the commentators :), etc. And you would have learned much more. But well... this is just an opinion (of a person thinking completely different than you, I am a quick answer-awarder).

Comment: hi, interestnng point of view... these could be my words. the reason why i post this here, including the pictures.. is because i did as u said. i started from scratch.. i even had it running as i needed it. then i changed a little detail.. and since then, thats it. i never came back to the state where it worked. so my reason to poast here was too see if i have errors in the source. if not, there is definately something wrong in my IDE or system...

Comment: I don't know what I can say to that. This kind of situations where various different elements are affecting each other (widths/heights, the ones you hardcode and the ones of the internal elements) might become a bit messy, but your code does not seem too complicated. What is clear is that you claim changes in columns but your code does not reflect any; and you claim a percentage (75%) which does not appear anywhere. I have tested your code and don't see the problem (have full control on any change). In your situation, I would go to bed, have some rest and try it tomorrow a little harder :)

Comment: thanks a lot! i needed to know this..
as it wont let me sleep anyway.. i will rebuild it on another machine now.... n see what happens then...

have a great day ;)

Comment: 1 last thing....

the 75% is as i wanted it to have... it was thought like this. the 2 outer elements (label + checkbox) have absolute values.. and the middle one was set to 75%.. before posting i changed it do .dock = fill..

and there could be a understanding problem from my side.. i thought setting all 3 controls to .dock = file while having autosize makes them same size at least - if all the other row/coloumn styles are overriden. as i do in the beginning...

but will see nw what happens on other machine..

Comment: Seriously, go to sleep. Think about all this carefully tomorrow and you will surely find the way through.